# What is the reason to use lodash / underscore .map() function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

In my current project I can see many `_.map()` usages almost identical like the following example:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var lodashMap = _.map(a, i => {
  if (i < 5) return i-1;
});
```

And I can't see any reason to not use just built-in `Array.map()` method like this:

```
var arrayMap = a.map(i => {
  if (i < 5) return i-1;
});
```

I know none of these mutates original array and made sure that the result is exactly the same: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqPMNQ

Also as we are using Typescript, lodash version loses the `i` parameter type, so I want to use `Array.map()` instead. Is there any difference I'm not aware of between `Array.map` and `_.map()`?

Comment: Underscore/LoDash predate the widespread availability of `Array.prototype.map()`.

Comment: Older browser don't implement `Array.prototype.map` so lodash is a pollyfill that work on both recent and older browsers!

Comment: So as our project target is es5 I can use `Array.map`, thanks for clarification!

Comment: One difference is that `_.map` can be used on array-like objects, whereas if you want to call `Array#map` on an array-like object, you need to use the awkward `Array.prototype.map.call(obj, ...)` or `[].map.call(obj, ...)`. Not a big difference, but `_.map` is more flexible. Also, `_.map()` can be used on ordinary objects, which `Array#map` can't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the purposes of the examples you have there, there's no effective difference between the two options and you're just as well off using `a.map()`.

However, there *are* some differences between `_.map` and `Array#map`.

One is that it can be called directly on array-like objects. (To do so with `Array#map` requires either attaching the function to the object and then calling it, or using the awkward approach with `.call()`.)

**Example:**

```js
var mapped = _.map(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), el => el.textContent);

console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li></ul>
```

You can also use `_.map` on objects that are not array-like. This is something that `Array#map` can't do at all.

**Example:**

```js
var myObj = { a: 1, b : 2 };
var mapped = _.map(myObj, (val, key) => key + val);

console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

It can also be used on `null` without throwing an error (it just returns an empty array). Depending on how you look at it, you may consider this a good thing or a bad thing, but it's a notable difference from the native `.map`.

**Example:**

```js
var myObj = null;
var mapped = _.map(myObj, (val, key) => key + val);

console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Aside from that, there's just the benefit of uniformity if you're combining it with a lot of other lodash/underscore functions.

Also, `_.map` can be used in an underscore/lodash chain.

**Example:**

```js
var values = [{ value: 10 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 13 }, { value: 7 }];
var result =  _.chain(values)
                .map(_.property('value'))
                .filter(v => v > 5)
                .sortBy()
                .value();
                
console.log(result);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Another very important thing is that lodash won't faill if the variable that should be holding the array is `null` - it will return empty array. With the native one you have to guard against this case.

Comment: @wojtiku Thanks, I didn't know that. I've added it to my answer.